# LINQ - Association mapping - Null reference on InsertOnSubmit

Tags: c#, .net, linq, exception, nullreferenceexception

I've a table Role associated in 1-many relation with table User in my database. I've created LINQ mapping classes manually:

```
[Table(Name="Role")]
public class Role
{
    private EntitySet<User> _Users;

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public int RoleID { get; set; }
    [Column] public string Name { get; set; }
    [Association(Name = "FK_User_Role", Storage = "_Users", ThisKey = "RoleID", OtherKey = "RoleID")]
    public EntitySet<User> Users
    {
        get{ return this._Users; }
        set{ this._Users.Assign(value);}
    }
}
```

The problem is that EntitySet Users can't be nullable so if later than I wish to create new role:

```
public override void CreateRole(string roleName)
{
    try
    {
        Role new_role = new Role();
        new_role.Name = roleName;
        _RolesRepository.SaveRole(new_role);
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

I'm getting error message listed below:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

> Line 36:             else Line 37:             {    Line 38:
>   rolesTable.InsertOnSubmit(role); ins = true; Line 39:             }
>   Line 40:
>
> Source File:
>   C:\inetpub\sklepomat\DomainModel\Concrete\SqlRolesRepository.cs
>   Line: 38

Stack Trace:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]
>   System.Data.Linq.Mapping.EntitySetDefSourceAccessor`2.GetValue(T
>   instance) +15
>
>   System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MetaAccessor`2.GetBoxedValue(Object instance)
>   +44    System.Data.Linq.StandardTrackedObject.HasDeferredLoader(MetaDataMember
>   deferredMember) +90
>   System.Data.Linq.StandardTrackedObject.get_HasDeferredLoaders() +102
>   System.Data.Linq.StandardChangeTracker.Track(MetaType mt, Object obj,
>   Dictionary`2 visited, Boolean recurse, Int32 level) +187
>
>   System.Data.Linq.StandardChangeTracker.Track(Object obj, Boolean
>   recurse) +80    System.Data.Linq.StandardChangeTracker.Track(Object
>   obj) +9    System.Data.Linq.Table`1.InsertOnSubmit(TEntity entity)
>   +172    DomainModel.Concrete.SqlRolesRepository.SaveRole(Role role) in C:\inetpub\sklepomat\DomainModel\Concrete\SqlRolesRepository.cs:38
>   DomainModel.Concrete.SklepomatRoleProvider.CreateRole(String roleName)
>   in
>   C:\inetpub\sklepomat\DomainModel\Concrete\SklepomatRoleProvider.cs:71 
>   System.Web.Security.Roles.CreateRole(String roleName) +73
>   WebUI.Controllers.TempController.ble() in
>   C:\inetpub\sklepomat\WebUI\Controllers\TempController.cs:29
>   lambda_method(ExecutionScope , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +74
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters) +17
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +178
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +24
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassa.b__7()
>   +52    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +254
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassc.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__9()
>   +19    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor,
>   IDictionary`2 parameters) +192
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName) +399
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +126
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
>   +27    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext
>   requestContext) +7
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext)
>   +151    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext) +57
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   httpContext) +7
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +181    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75

I assume that's because `EntitySet<User> _Users` equals to `null`...
Am I right !? 
What should be assigned to `_Users` if it can't by nullable !?

**UPDATE:**

Exception is raised

```
        try { rolesTable.InsertOnSubmit(role);}
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;

        }
```

Where role object's fields are set to:

```
_Users = null,
Name = "New name",
RoleID = 0,
Users = null
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a link to great tutorial related to LINQ mapping: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/linqtutorial.aspx My final code is:

```
[Table(Name="Role")]
public class Role
{
    private EntitySet<User> _Users = new EntitySet<User>();

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public int RoleID { get; set; }
    [Column] public string Name { get; set; }
    [Association(Name = "FK_User_Role", Storage = "_Users", ThisKey = "RoleID", OtherKey = "RoleID")]
    public EntitySet<User> Users
    {
        get{ return this._Users; }
        set{ this._Users.Assign(value);}
        }
}
```

Comment: `private EntitySet<User> _Users = new EntitySet<User>();` - worked for me

Comment: You should accept your own answer if it describes the way you solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a problem in your code and/or schema. The Role.RoleID property, which is your primary key, is a nullable int type. This cannot be. Primary key values cannot contain null values.

Comment: It was changed to nullable because RoleID is generated in database so I thought that I cannot pass any value and that's the reason of error. I've changed it back to regular int type but it doesn't fix the problem...  (see UPDATE)